# Suddenly I can't connect all of my Wi-Fi devices

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, router, android

I'm facing a very strange problem with my home network. I own five Wi-Fi devices:

- a desktop PC (connected using [this Sitecom dongle](https://www.sitecom.com/en/n300-usb-adapter/wla-2100/p/1563)) running Windows 10
- a notebook running Windows 10
- an Android Nexus running Android 4.4
- a Nokia Lumia 735 running Windows 10 Mobile
- an Apple iPad running iOS 9.3.2

Everything has always been fine and there have been situations where I connected all of those devices at the same time. The router (Sitecom X3 N300) is configured to enable 802.11n signal protected with WPA2 key. DHCP Server is enabled while DNS Relay is not. Channel selection is set to Auto and right now is 13 (I'm in Italy).

But a few days ago, some of my devices stopped connecting to the network. In particular, the Nexus (android) and the iPad can see and connect to my WiFi network, but then they don't receive any data when surfing the web. So, WiFi icons shows the "connected" status, but pages never loads.

And this happens **only on Android and Apple** devices. I tried to *forget* and reconnect the WiFi network on those devices, and also I tried to turn off all the other devices and connect only one of them. Tried also a full router's settings reset but nothing. How can it be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turned out to be... the IPv6 connection.
My router was configured to provide both IPv4 and IPv6 connections through my Italian provider (TIM.it). Setting it to enable just the IPv4 connection solved the problem!

Apparently there is a temporary problem with IPv6 network, but all of my Windows devices always used IPv4 (or have the ability to switch to v4 when v6 is not available, don't know) so they never suffered for it. Instead, Android and iPad kept trying the IPv6 with no luck... so I forced everyone to use IPv4, for now.